# Need help in displaying a Custom ArcGIS map in power bi

Tags: javascript, html, css, powerbi, arcgis

I am working on a Power BI Proof of Concept project that involves ArcGIS Map visuals. My organization has custom ArcGIS maps that need to be integrated with the Power BI report. The challenge here is that the project needs to be deployed in an environment where ArcGIS online access (login & connect to the Argis portal through the Argis map visualization) is not working.

The idea is to get the HTML code of the map and use it directly in the report to avoid access issues. I tried the method below.

I hosted the HTML code of the map on GitHub and established a GitHub page. Following this, I created a Power BI table, with the URL as one of the column values. Subsequently, I crafted a measure based on the table and integrated the measure's value into an HTML iframe in another measure, as demonstrated below

```html
IFrame = 
"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src='"& [murl] &"' style='position: fixed; width:100%; height:100%'></iframe>

</body>
</html>"
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>SceneLayerView - query statistics by geometry | Sample | ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript 4.28</title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .esri-ui-top-right {
        max-height: 100%;
      }

      #queryDiv,
      #resultDiv {
        min-width: 250px;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 10px;
        display: none;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      .geometry-options {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
      .geometry-button {
        flex: 1;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-image: none;
      }
      .geometry-button-selected {
        background: #4c4c4c;
        color: #fff;
      }

      #bufferNum {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 2.5em auto 0;
      }

      .count {
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Load the Chart.js library -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.28/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.28/"></script>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/WebScene",
        "esri/views/SceneView",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Sketch/SketchViewModel",
        "esri/widgets/Slider",
        "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/core/promiseUtils"
      ], (WebScene, SceneView, GraphicsLayer, SketchViewModel, Slider, geometryEngine, Graphic, promiseUtils) => {
        // Load webscene and display it in a SceneView
        const webscene = new WebScene({
          portalItem: {
            id: "fb5948b2bb76439792786000b942e5b7"
          }
        });
        // create the SceneView
        const view = new SceneView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: webscene
        });
        window.view = view;
        // add a GraphicsLayer for the sketches and the buffer
        const sketchLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        const bufferLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        view.map.addMany([bufferLayer, sketchLayer]);

        let sceneLayer = null;
        let sceneLayerView = null;
        let bufferSize = 0;

        // Assign scene layer once webscene is loaded and initialize UI
        webscene.load().then(() => {
          sceneLayer = webscene.layers.find((layer) => {
            return layer.title === "Helsinki textured buildings";
          });
          sceneLayer.outFields = ["buildingMaterial", "yearCompleted"];

          view.whenLayerView(sceneLayer).then((layerView) => {
            sceneLayerView = layerView;
            queryDiv.style.display = "block";
          });
        });

        view.ui.add([queryDiv], "bottom-left");
        view.ui.add([resultDiv], "top-right");

        // use SketchViewModel to draw polygons that are used as a query
        let sketchGeometry = null;
        const sketchViewModel = new SketchViewModel({
          layer: sketchLayer,
          defaultUpdateOptions: {
            tool: "reshape",
            toggleToolOnClick: false
          },
          view: view,
          defaultCreateOptions: { hasZ: false }
        });

        sketchViewModel.on("create", (event) => {
          if (event.state === "complete") {
            sketchGeometry = event.graphic.geometry;
            runQuery();
          }
        });

        sketchViewModel.on("update", (event) => {
          if (event.state === "complete") {
            sketchGeometry = event.graphics[0].geometry;
            runQuery();
          }
        });
        // draw geometry buttons - use the selected geometry to sktech
        const pointBtn = document.getElementById("point-geometry-button");
        const lineBtn = document.getElementById("line-geometry-button");
        const polygonBtn = document.getElementById("polygon-geometry-button");
        pointBtn.addEventListener("click", geometryButtonsClickHandler);
        lineBtn.addEventListener("click", geometryButtonsClickHandler);
        polygonBtn.addEventListener("click", geometryButtonsClickHandler);
        function geometryButtonsClickHandler(event) {
          const geometryType = event.target.value;
          clearGeometry();
          sketchViewModel.create(geometryType);
        }

        const bufferNumSlider = new Slider({
          container: "bufferNum",
          min: 0,
          max: 500,
          steps: 1,
          visibleElements: {
            labels: true
          },
          precision: 0,
          labelFormatFunction: (value, type) => {
            return `${value.toString()}m`;
          },
          values: [0]
        });
        // get user entered values for buffer
        bufferNumSlider.on(["thumb-change", "thumb-drag"], bufferVariablesChanged);
        function bufferVariablesChanged(event) {
          bufferSize = event.value;
          runQuery();
        }
        // Clear the geometry and set the default renderer
        const clearGeometryBtn = document.getElementById("clearGeometry");
        clearGeometryBtn.addEventListener("click", clearGeometry);

        // Clear the geometry and set the default renderer
        function clearGeometry() {
          sketchGeometry = null;
          sketchViewModel.cancel();
          sketchLayer.removeAll();
          bufferLayer.removeAll();
          clearHighlighting();
          clearCharts();
          resultDiv.style.display = "none";
        }

        // set the geometry query on the visible SceneLayerView
        const debouncedRunQuery = promiseUtils.debounce(() => {
          if (!sketchGeometry) {
            return;
          }

          resultDiv.style.display = "block";
          updateBufferGraphic(bufferSize);
          return promiseUtils.eachAlways([queryStatistics(), updateSceneLayer()]);
        });

        function runQuery() {
          debouncedRunQuery().catch((error) => {
            if (error.name === "AbortError") {
              return;
            }

            console.error(error);
          });
        }

        // Set the renderer with objectIds
        let highlightHandle = null;
        function clearHighlighting() {
          if (highlightHandle) {
            highlightHandle.remove();
            highlightHandle = null;
          }
        }

        function highlightBuildings(objectIds) {
          // Remove any previous highlighting
          clearHighlighting();
          const objectIdField = sceneLayer.objectIdField;
          document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = objectIds.length;

          highlightHandle = sceneLayerView.highlight(objectIds);
        }

        // update the graphic with buffer
        function updateBufferGraphic(buffer) {
          // add a polygon graphic for the buffer
          if (buffer > 0) {
            const bufferGeometry = geometryEngine.geodesicBuffer(sketchGeometry, buffer, "meters");
            if (bufferLayer.graphics.length === 0) {
              bufferLayer.add(
                new Graphic({
                  geometry: bufferGeometry,
                  symbol: sketchViewModel.polygonSymbol
                })
              );
            } else {
              bufferLayer.graphics.getItemAt(0).geometry = bufferGeometry;
            }
          } else {
            bufferLayer.removeAll();
          }
        }

        function updateSceneLayer() {
          const query = sceneLayerView.createQuery();
          query.geometry = sketchGeometry;
          query.distance = bufferSize;
          return sceneLayerView.queryObjectIds(query).then(highlightBuildings);
        }

        let yearChart = null;
        let materialChart = null;

        function queryStatistics() {
          const statDefinitions = [
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN buildingMaterial = 'concrete or lightweight concrete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "material_concrete",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN buildingMaterial = 'brick' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "material_brick",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN buildingMaterial = 'wood' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "material_wood",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN buildingMaterial = 'steel' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "material_steel",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField:
                "CASE WHEN buildingMaterial IN ('concrete or lightweight concrete', 'brick', 'wood', 'steel') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "material_other",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN (yearCompleted >= '1850' AND yearCompleted <= '1899') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "year_1850",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN (yearCompleted >= '1900' AND yearCompleted <= '1924') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "year_1900",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN (yearCompleted >= '1925' AND yearCompleted <= '1949') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "year_1925",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN (yearCompleted >= '1950' AND yearCompleted <= '1974') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "year_1950",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN (yearCompleted >= '1975' AND yearCompleted <= '1999') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "year_1975",
              statisticType: "sum"
            },
            {
              onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN (yearCompleted >= '2000' AND yearCompleted <= '2015') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
              outStatisticFieldName: "year_2000",
              statisticType: "sum"
            }
          ];
          const query = sceneLayerView.createQuery();
          query.geometry = sketchGeometry;
          query.distance = bufferSize;
          query.outStatistics = statDefinitions;

          return sceneLayerView.queryFeatures(query).then((result) => {
            const allStats = result.features[0].attributes;
            updateChart(materialChart, [
              allStats.material_concrete,
              allStats.material_brick,
              allStats.material_wood,
              allStats.material_steel,
              allStats.material_other
            ]);
            updateChart(yearChart, [
              allStats.year_1850,
              allStats.year_1900,
              allStats.year_1925,
              allStats.year_1950,
              allStats.year_1975,
              allStats.year_2000
            ]);
          }, console.error);
        }

        // Updates the given chart with new data
        function updateChart(chart, dataValues) {
          chart.data.datasets[0].data = dataValues;
          chart.update();
        }

        function createYearChart() {
          const yearCanvas = document.getElementById("year-chart");
          yearChart = new Chart(yearCanvas.getContext("2d"), {
            type: "horizontalBar",
            data: {
              labels: ["1850-1899", "1900-1924", "1925-1949", "1950-1974", "1975-1999", "2000-2015"],
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: "Build year",
                  backgroundColor: "#149dcf",
                  stack: "Stack 0",
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              responsive: false,
              legend: {
                display: false
              },
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Build year"
              },
              scales: {
                xAxes: [
                  {
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true,
                      precision: 0
                    }
                  }
                ],
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    stacked: true
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          });
        }
        function createMaterialChart() {
          const materialCanvas = document.getElementById("material-chart");
          materialChart = new Chart(materialCanvas.getContext("2d"), {
            type: "doughnut",
            data: {
              labels: ["Concrete", "Brick", "Wood", "Steel", "Other"],
              datasets: [
                {
                  backgroundColor: ["#FD7F6F", "#7EB0D5", "#B2E061", "#BD7EBE", "#FFB55A"],
                  borderWidth: 0,
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              responsive: false,
              cutoutPercentage: 35,
              legend: {
                position: "bottom"
              },
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Building Material"
              }
            }
          });
        }

        function clearCharts() {
          updateChart(materialChart, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
          updateChart(yearChart, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
          document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = 0;
        }

        createYearChart();
        createMaterialChart();
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
    <div id="queryDiv" class="esri-widget">
      <b>Query by geometry</b><br />
      <br />Draw a geometry to query by:
      <div class="geometry-options">
        <button
          class="esri-widget--button esri-icon-map-pin geometry-button"
          id="point-geometry-button"
          value="point"
          title="Query by point"
        ></button>
        <button
          class="esri-widget--button esri-icon-polyline geometry-button"
          id="line-geometry-button"
          value="polyline"
          title="Query by line"
        ></button>
        <button
          class="esri-widget--button esri-icon-polygon geometry-button"
          id="polygon-geometry-button"
          value="polygon"
          title="Query by polygon"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="tooltip">
        <label for="bufferNum">Set a geometry buffer size:</label>
        <div id="bufferNum"></div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <button class="esri-button" id="clearGeometry" type="button">Clear</button>
    </div>

    <div id="resultDiv" class="esri-widget">
      <div class="count">
        Selected Buildings:
        <div class="count" id="count">0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="charts">
        <div>
          <canvas id="year-chart" height="250" width="260" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <canvas id="material-chart" width="250" height="300" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway i can use this HTML code directly and display an interactive MAP in power bi instead of hosting it in github & use Iframe. Is there any visual other than "HTML content" can be used to display rich HTML (with Java script, CSS) ?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why is ArcGIS online access not working? Seems like an awful lot of steps, workaround, hacks to work around this. Which ever issues/restrictions you have with "HTML content" , you will have with any other visual.

Comment: The main problem is Arcgis for Power bi needs online connectivity with arcgis servers and the power bi inside the environment not allowing it.